Attempting to make number generator and output to file
I am attempting to crack a SHA512 string of which I know a few parameters, that is that the number hashed is between 16500000000 and 17000000000, but the numbers are too large as I get the error "Invalid number. Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision". I was using a counter found from this post. What I was attempting with this code below:
@echo off
set var1=16500000000

:loop
    set /a var1=%var1%+1

echo %var1% > .\Unhashed\%var1%.txt
ping localhost -n 1 >NUL
if %var1% EQU 17000000000 (
    goto :end
) else (
    goto :loop
)

:end
    pause

Is for it to generate a text file named each number generated (Along with the # inside), to which I could then automatically hash and test against as a database with the known hash that was provided.
I am not smart enough to try and attempt to implement more code to get around this :(

The bad news is that batch uses signed 32-bit integers, which have a maximum value of 2,147,483,647. The good news is that because you're using between 16.5 and 17 billion, you can just chop off the first two digits and increment the remaining digits normally.
@echo off
for /L %%A in (500000000,1,999999999) do (
    echo 16%%A >"Unhashed\16%%A.txt"
)
echo 17000000000 >"Unhashed\17000000000.txt"

It's worth noting that there's almost certainly a way to achieve your final goal without making half a billion text files (and all the disk space that entails), but I'd need more information about your exact situation.

I found out how to get what I needed, thank you
